# Лука, излучина, но при чем тут лук?

Tags: этимология

Лук (оружие), лука седла, излучина — все эти слова означают некий изгиб. Но каким боком относится к ним лук-растение? Он вроде бы нигде не изгибается, если, конечно, здоровый)))

Comment: Локон оттуда же - из того же корня - лок, клок (что-то свернутое или выдернутое).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лук (оружие) образовалось из общеславянского "lokъ" в значении "изгиб", отсюда же, как Вы правильно заметили, и лука, и излучина.

Этимология же лука (растения) менее понятна. Есть две основные гипотезы:

- Исконное слово. От древнерусского слова "лукъ", или общеславянского  "lukъ".
- Заимствовано из древнегерманского  от "lauka" .  В древнеисландском находим laukr, в немецком – Lauch.

Answer (score 3):

Это обычный омоним, как и ключ, брак...

Comment: Самое  забавное,  что  лук - растение  тоже  "выбрасывает"  стрелки.

Answer (score 2):

Лук-оружие, лука седла и излучина реки к луку-растению отношения не имеют. Изначально были разные гласные звуки, просто с течением времени утрачено произношение "носовых" гласных. Были в русском языке так называемые "Юсы" - "Юс большой" и "Юс малый" - буквы, обозначавшие "носовые" гласные. Сейчас их можно услышать только в глухих деревнях у стариков, в диалектных говорах, и то лишь в отдельных словах. Так что эти слова - даже не однокоренные, просто со временем их фонетическая оболочка стала похожей.

Answer (score 0):

Не соглашусь с происхождением лука (растения). По крайней мере, по-латышски - "loks" (почти [у]). Этимологи, если я не заблуждаюсь, утверждают, что схожие с "древними" словами русского языка слова можно отыскать в латышском языке, лучше сохранившем "старый" словарный запас.  Я бы связал "лук" с "лучом". Подкрепление этого утверждения вижу в "стрелках" лука, чеснока. Кстати, почему тогда "лук", но... "чеснок", если в немецком - "Lauch" и (!) "Knoblauch", а в латышском - "loks" и "kiploki"? Видимо, и там, и там речь идет о "клубнях"?

Что заставило русский язык свернуть с проторенной дорожки?

Граждане филологи, не судите, пожалуйста, строго доморощенного этимолога. Это скорее вопрос, чем утверждение.

Answer (score 0):

В смысле лук не имеет изгиба? Когда мы говорим про растение лук, то ведь мы говорим не только о луковых побегах (вторично), но и о собственно луке репчатом. Именно от луковицы, на мой взгляд, название такое, какое оно есть.

Если разрезать лук вдоль, мы получим тот самый изгиб луки или даже множество изгибов.